# How to change background color of a tab when clicked on

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a `TabLayout` and it displays about 4 tabs. When I click on one tab, the background color is a disgusting yellowish highlight (and then goes back to normal when I release). How would I change it so that it is white during the transition to the desired fragment.

Here is my app theme

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

and here is the `Tablayout` and `ViewPager`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/headBlue"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and here are the dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1

Create drawable file for selector named **tab_selector.xml** in your drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

#### Step 2

Create **tab_background_selected.xml** file in drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

#### Step 3

Create **tab_background_unselected.xml** file in drawable directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
</shape>
```

#### Step 4

Finally, apply this to your style.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_selector</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this is changing the colors of the tabs permanently. When press down on a tab, it's background color is like a light yellowish color (or it appears that way with my tablayout color: #00A6FF), and then when you release, it goes back to the default background color. I want to change it so it appears white.